# Qt Charts with ignition gui plugin

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello every one :D
i had a problem with running Qt Charts on a ignition gui plugin, i mentioned it in a previous question https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24632/ignition-gui-plugin-qt-charts-problem/

but now i found out that it is a common issue in Qt Charts itself, it dose not run with QGuiApplication and requires QApplication
and ignition gui uses the QGuiApplication, but i tried to modify it and replace it with QApplication and it worked

[image: Screenshot from 2020-03-27 11-07-17]
[image: Screenshot from 2020-03-27 11-06-55]

....................................................

**but of course it might be an invalid solution, as i don't know how it will affect the other parts of the ignition gui
so , is there is any other ideas can i do to run qt charts components on QApplication without affecting the other parts of the applicaton ?**

### Update

ok, I modified the Application.hh & Application.cc and replaced the QGuiApplication with QApplication and modified the CMakeLists files (QApplication requires the Qt5Widgets library).

it seems to be good, the test cases are fine, i tested the ign-gui & ign-gazebo and this is the results
100% success in ign-gui , 97% success in ign-gazebo (this is the same percentage for me before the modifying)

it tested on version 3 of both of them, ign-gazebo3 & ign-gui3

[image: gui_test]
[image: gazebo_test]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24669/qt-charts-with-ignition-gui-plugin/) by [Amr Elsersy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24856/amr-elsersy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-03-28**:
I moved your other answer to the question under an "Update" header

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-03-28**:
That sounds great, thank you for testing all that! Unfortunately, that change would break ABI, so we can't add it to Blueprint (`ign-gui2`) or Citadel (`ign-gui3`). So you're welcome to open a PR against the next Ignition version, Dome, which is currently the `default` branch of `ign-gui`  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Nice! Glad to see you found a workaround!

You're right that `QtCharts` needs `QApplication`, I hadn't realized that. I see 2 options:

1. Change `ign-gui` to use `QApplication` and test all `ign-gazebo` plugins to verify things still work. This change breaks ABI and would need to go into the upcoming Ignition release, Dome.
2. If the above doesn't work, we won't be able to use `QtCharts` and will need to look for another approach.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1